# How do I get computed column using db_select?

Tags: database

I require sum(points)? Any help on what to add in the sample code given below?

```
$query = db_select('digitaliq_question_points','n')
  ->fields('n',array('points'))
  ->condition("node_id", $node->nid, '=')
  ->condition('n.fld_group', $fields, 'IN');

$points = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of the [`addExpression()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7) method:

```
$query = db_select('digitaliq_question_points','n')
  ->fields('n',array('points'))
  ->condition("node_id", $node->nid, '=') 
  ->condition('n.fld_group', $fields, 'IN');

$alias = $query->addExpression('SUM(points)', 'sum_of_points');

$points = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Obviously that might need to change slightly based on your return value/grouping requirements but that's the method you're looking for.